# Can AMD dual graphics (APU + GPU ) be activated on demand?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I've been thinking on building a pc with an AMD A8 7600 with a r7 250 card. I'm looking for something that can do some light gaming while keeping consumption as low as possible. The APU+ GPU seems like a reasonable solution but I have some questions

- Can the dedicated gpu be turned on and off on demand like some laptops switch between integrated and dedicated gpu?
- Does turning off dual graphics actually turns off the gpu? is it consuming (noticeable) electricity when off?

Comment: The amount of power the APU is going to consume is not going to change if you diable or enable the iGPU by any significant amount,

Comment: The way I understand what he asks he never asks about the iGPU at all, he is asking about the dedicated R7 250.

Comment: @Probst, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD has power saving stuff built in already. I believe it should do what you want out of the box assuming the APU is considered the primary card in crossfire. If you run crossfire with multiple dedicated cards then when you are not using the GPU the non primary cards automatically power down to a sort of sleep mode where their fans don't even spin and they are only about 10 degrees above ambient.

However, that being said I would recommend you do some research and be absolutely sure that you want to use this set up. Crossfire can be a bit of a pain and I would not do it with such a weak card. You would likely be much better off with even say an R7 260X. The typical advice is to buy the best single GPU you can afford and not to go dual GPU unless you are buying one of the best GPUs available.

Comment: well, amd recommends that card to be used along the A8 7600, which is the APU I have in mind

Comment: "assuming the APU is considered the primary card in crossfire" this seems to be the important point. if the main gpu is the apu then the secondary (gpu) should go to sleep when not needed if ULPC (ultra low power consumption ) is enabled.

Comment: AMD recommends that one because it is the only one that crossfires with the APU. That doesn't mean it is a particularly good choice for a setup, it's just a choice that works alongside that APU. It depends just how light your gaming is whether or not you will be happy with it, I would just recommend looking into crossfire more closely before investing.

Comment: yes.that is what this question is about :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here, assuming you want to continue with your mentioned configuration, is simply to ensure that your power settings allow for the additional graphics card to power itself down when not in use.

I would advise using maximum power savings for your situation, though if you notice any issues with excessive graphic delay during normal us I would change to moderate power savings.

As show in this image:

[image: Power Options]
.

As well, I would advise that you check your current power setting for processor power management, as setting that to 5-10% as well would ensure that both your GPU and APU are capable of reducing their power consumption when not in use.

Comment: I would be careful with this... AMD already has it's own power saving settings in Catalyst and I think this might conflict with those and cause issues. I had some issues with my 7970's powering up and down at the wrong times and it was because of something similar.

Comment: Always depends on the user's scenario, which is why I included "if you notice any issues with excessive graphic delay during normal us I would change to moderate power savings."

Those settings by AMD are configured with compatibility for the Moderate power savings option, which is default in most Windows installations. Maximum savings works for some people, but not everyone, depending on the uses.